# I have tried to trigger push notifications to my mobile number from sfmc mobile push

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, mobilepush, mobileconnect

I tried to trigger notifications but the status seems to be sent but I did nt receive any push notifications. Even I didn't see any issue

Comment: How do you trigger the Push Notification?

Comment: I have created a journey and entry source us DE with attributes Firstname, email, phone number

Answer (score 1):

In order to send Push Notification through Journey Builder, a Subscriber Key/Contact Key in the DE source needs to be already tied with the registered contact in Mobile Push channel.

You can check by going to Contact Builder > All Contacts > Mobile Push channel then put the subscriber key on the search bar. If no records found, it means it hasn't been tied correctly in Mobile Push channel yet.

Comment: So @Duc Le as soon as we install the mobile app and register the user. Contact key will be created and tied to -Mobile push channel.Am I right

Comment: @SFMCDeveloper yes but the important thing is does the the registered contact key value in Mobile Push channel match with the contact key value in your DE source? Have you checked like I mentioned above yet?

Comment: Yes but both are same same. Bur device id has not been created

Comment: Try to check in `_PushAddress` data view if the device token and platform field are matching with the one you are having. FYI if the app was uninstalled then reinstalled, the device token of that contact may be changed

Comment: Ok thank you Duc Le